# getting error code 1067:invalid default value for order date

Tags: mysql, sql

sql

```
 CREATE TABLE TBL_ORDER 
    (
        REF_NO CHAR(14) NOT NULL,
        ORD_DTE DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '01/01/1990',
        CUST_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        CATEGORY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        PRODUCT VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        SALES NUMERIC(18, 5),
        PROFIT NUMERIC(18, 5)
    );
```

Tried to run this code but giving error on `Ord_Date`,
please help

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_ORDER 
(
    REF_NO CHAR(14) NOT NULL,
    ORD_DTE DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '01/01/1990',
    CUST_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CATEGORY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRODUCT VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    SALES NUMERIC(18, 5),
    PROFIT NUMERIC(18, 5)
);
```

**Expected output:** it should have executed

**Actual:** giving error date default value

Comment: Use `YYYY-MM-DD` format for dates but not `DD/MM/YYYY` - just `ORD_DTE DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1990-01-01',`

Comment: You should review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html AND I would use the more descriptive(in my view) decimal data type rather than numeric,